# Is there a way in bash -o vi mode to have the prompt indicate normal/command mode, etc

Tags: bash, vim

I use vi mode in bash all of the time. It would be really useful to see visually if I am in command mode or insert mode.

For example when I want to search the history, typing `/my_search` in either mode looks the same until I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and by then it's too late. I find myself pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> much more than necessary just to make sure I'm in the right mode....

Comment: Disable vi mode and use `<C-x><C-e>` when you actually need to edit something.

Comment: You can use the output from `bind -v` to find the current keymap. You could possibly map the enter/leave insert bindings to set a shell variable/etc. appropriately but I'm not sure where you would show that value at that point. (The prompt doesn't work so it would need to be somewhere more freely updateable... unless you wanted to start playing with prompt sizes and moving the cursor around to over-write a string in a specific place, etc.)

Comment: I found this page that does what you want: http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/205517/Display-Vim-mode-in-Bash-prompt -- requires bash 4.3

Answer (score 2):

You can configure this in the `.inputrc` file that readline uses.

```
set show-mode-in-prompt
```

For me, this draws a `+` as the first character in insert mode, a `:` in normal mode, and no character in search mode.

(You can also enable vi mode in here using `set editing-mode vi`, which will enable it for all programs using readline, such as the python and ruby interpreters, instead of just bash).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this in the prompt itself, but I think **a cursor shape/color indicator is at least as useful**.

The following setup gives **a square, green, block cursor in normal mode, and a skinny, flat, gray underline cursor when in insert mode**. There may be a way to do it in bash, but I have it working in Zsh, so I'll share this. It happens to be in URxvt, but should work in xterm, too. In `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Modal cursor color for vi's insert/normal modes.
zle-keymap-select () {
  if [ $KEYMAP = vicmd ]; then
    echo -ne "\033]12;Green\007"
    echo -ne "\033[2 q"
  else
    echo -ne "\033]12;Grey\007"
    echo -ne "\033[4 q"
  fi
}
zle -N zle-keymap-select
zle-line-init () {
  zle -K viins
  echo -ne "\033]12;Gray\007"
  echo -ne "\033[4 q"
}
zle -N zle-line-init
```

Resources: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95078 AND https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115009/how-to-change-the-cursor-theme-in-cli

EDIT: I posted a [comprehensive guide](http://www.micahelliott.com/posts/2015-07-20-vim-zsh-tmux-cursor.html) to getting this working in a combo of vim, zsh, tmux, and urxvt.